# Issues creating tasks using Gulp

Tags: npm, gulp

I'm having issues creating tasks using Gulp (and gulp --tasks). I'm not sure if running "npm i" has anything to do with it

```
Kayas-MacBook-Pro:~ pineapplelaptop$ npm i

> fsevents@1.2.12 install /Users/pineapplelaptop/node_modules/fsevents
> node-gyp rebuild

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLILeo' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI' found at '/'.

gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:351:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:311:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.4.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/pineapplelaptop/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.12 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.12 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

audited 6827 packages in 3.104s

8 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

Kayas-MacBook-Pro:~ pineapplelaptop$ clear

Kayas-MacBook-Pro:~ pineapplelaptop$ npm i

> fsevents@1.2.12 install /Users/pineapplelaptop/node_modules/fsevents
> node-gyp rebuild

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLILeo' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI' found at '/'.

gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:351:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:311:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.4.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/pineapplelaptop/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.12 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.12 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

audited 6827 packages in 3.112s

8 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

Kayas-MacBook-Pro:~ pineapplelaptop$ gulp
Using gulpfile ~/gulpfile.js
Task never defined: default
To list available tasks, try running: gulp --tasks
Kayas-MacBook-Pro:~ pineapplelaptop$ gulp --tasks
Tasks for ~/gulpfile.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it says in the error

> gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!

You need to install Xcode and the Xcode Command-line Tools. These are installed when you open Xcode for the first time. Alternatively, you can install them by running `xcode-select --install`